# LWC import of custom address field particles imports parent field

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-experience

Can you please check what I am wrong with?
I import the street field of the custom address field as:

```js
import SobjectField__Address__c__LocalAddress__Street__s
    from "@salesforce/schema/Address__c.LocalAddress__Street__s";
```

But then if I use it, it works like `LocalAddress__c` field not `Street__s` part

If I run a console log

```js
console.log("SobjectField__Address__c__LocalAddress__Street__s");
console.log(SobjectField__Address__c__LocalAddress__Street__s.fieldApiName);
```

I receive:

```
SobjectField__Address__c__LocalAddress__Street__s (aura_proddebug.js:34232)
LocalAddress__c (aura_proddebug.js:34232)
```